# What exactly Derice referring to by saying "it" word?

Tags: meaning

Derice asking Blizter to coach him for Olympics.

> Derice: Please, Mr. Blitzer, just give me a chance. If I don't have
>   what it takes, we'll forget the whole thing.
>
> Blizter: Believe me, kid, you do not have what **it** takes.

What exactly Derice referring to by saying "it" word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dialogue is from [Cool Runnings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cool_Runnings), an American comedy sports film.

In the context of the whole [conversation](http://www.moviequotedb.com/movies/cool-runnings.html), "it" in "what it takes" refers to special qualities which one aimed at winning a competition needs to have. Although those are not clearly voiced in the dialogue, they are known to any athlete or coach.

Answer (score 0):

**what it takes** is considered as one noun here. It refers to skills mostly but can also refer to intelligence or some trait.

By saying, "**what it takes**" they can mean anything.

- If I don't have **[what it takes]**...
- ...you do not have **[what it takes]**...

My guess is that **what it takes** refers to some necessary skill.